# How to search for a specific field and then use it in Field Calculator

Tags: python, arcpy, field-calculator

I have a piece of code where the goal is to search through the field names within a feature, select any field based on a specific character (in this case "z") and then use that selected field within a Field Calculator Expression. My experience with python is limited, see the code below;

for var in List_Input:

```
filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(str(var)))[0]
arcpy.Select_analysis(var, env+"\\"+filename, "")
var_sel = env+"\\"+filename
arcpy.AddField_management(var_sel,"VR_Rate","Double")
VRField = arcpy.ListFields(var_sel,)

VRField_Calc = ""
for field in VRField:
    if "z" in field.name:
        VRField_Calc = field.name
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(var_sel,"VR_Rate", [VRField_Calc+" + 2"])
```

The bottom half of the code is where the issues arise. How to pass the "VRField_Calc" (field name) into the Calculate Field Expression?

Comment: You need to tell it which field.  "VR_Rate" should be the VRField_Calc variable.

Comment: the function works as follows; CalculateField_management (in_table, field, expression, {expression_type}, {code_block}) within my equation var_sel = input table, "VR_Rate" = field. I just need to know how to pass the VRField_Calc (variable containing the found field) into the Expression. I am intentionally calculating the "VR_Rate" field. I wish for it to contain VRField_Calc +2 (in this example).

Comment: Fantastic, thank you for you help. This works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(var_sel, "VR_Rate", '!' + VRField_Calc + '! + 2', "PYTHON_9.3")
```

To search for a specific field before calculating:

```
findField = 'some_field_name'

for field in VRField:
if field.name == findField:
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(var_sel, "VR_Rate", '!' + field.name + '! + 2', "PYTHON_9.3")
```

Comment: What about searching for a specific field name before calculating?

Comment: @artwork21 See edits.